# apscheduler 3.6.1 background scheduler mysteriously stops without event or error

Tags: python-3.x, apscheduler

Running 3.6.1 against Postgresql store.  Scheduler runs for hours (or days) processing requests and eventually I see:

"Adding job tentatively -- it will be properly scheduled when the scheduler starts"

There is no shutdown event logged, the scheduler just seems flagged as stopped. My assumption is that if it got an exception processing jobs it would have logged it and then retried after a certain number of seconds.

Any ideas how to debug?

Comment: Is this in any way reproduceable?

Comment: Since it is running against AWS RDS, we did note the DB server went offline for a few minutes (we front end if with pgbouncer) during that time. We saw it in another log.  So that would be the clue. I will try to reproduce, for sure apscheduler (at DEBUG level logging) didn't report anything it just stopped processing jobs.

Comment: Tried to reproduce directly at postgres and with pgbouncer in the middle, apscheduler recovers fine in both these cases. Do note that I am running rypc as part of the application in order to have a external method to add/delete jobs. Not sure how that could come into play but I thought I would mention it.

Comment: Mimicking almost exactly your example here: https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/blob/master/examples/rpc/server.py